# Regarding square-free numbers and their doubles.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, inequality

Is it true that between any  non-prime square-free number and it's double is another non-prime  square-free number?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let the non-prime square-free number be denoted as $\prod_{n=1}^{k} p_n$, where $k > 1$, and $p_{n} > p_{n-1}$ for all $n$. By Bertrand's postulate, we are guaranteed a prime $p$ such that $p_k < p < 2p_k$. Then we must have

$$\prod_{n=1}^{k} p_n < p\prod_{n=1}^{k-1} p_n < 2\prod_{n=1}^{k} p_n,$$

and since $p > p_k$, $p > p_n$ for all $n$, meaning $p$ is distinct from all $p_n$; therefore, there exists a composite square-free number between any composite square-free number and its double.

Comment: Is this a partly non-trivial correct observation?

Comment: @user128932 What do you mean by that?

Comment: Is this a useful observation that isn't easily dismissed as trivial?

Comment: I'm not sure how useful it is, but it's definitely not trivial. It follows rather immediately from Bertrand's postulate, but I don't think that makes it trivial.

Answer (score 0):

Aside from the trivial pair 1, 2, yes: [Bertrand's Postulate](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bertrand's_postulate) tells you there is not merely a squarefree number, but a **prime** number, which is trivially squarefree.

Comment: The recent edit to the OP clarifies that both the original and sought square-free numbers are composite.